# Is slowdown while using Starite Vision normal?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

Whenever i use starite vision the game slowns down a bit. Is this normal aka should starite vision really give the slowmotion effect?

I'm asking because i am kind of getting annoyed by it and was just wondering is the game made that way, or is the performance of my PC going down while in starite vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Starite Vision is not supposed to slow you down. It is a performance issue on your end.

Comment: Ok thx. I wonder how can something like starite vision slow my game down. I mean it doesn't really do any high-end effects.

Comment: I occasionally get a micro-lag when I first click on the Starite Vision, but that's about it. I've tested several times, I always seem to run / fly / swim at the same exact speed in and out of that vision.